# Delete double entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a Microsoft SQL Server table `[database].[dbo].[UserInAppPurchase]` with this columns:

```
   [Id]
  ,[UserEmail]
  ,[UserId]
  ,[PurchaseDate]
  ,[ProductId]
  ,[TransactionId]
  ,[OriginalTransactionId]
  ,[ValidationTime]
  ,[ValidationReceipt]
  ,[ValidFrom]
  ,[ValidTo]
  ,[Platfrom]
```

We have multiple entries with the same `[TransactionID]`, but per `TransactionID` only one row should be there. Thus we would like to delete all rows with same `TransactionID` and keep the one with the lowest `[Id]`.

Thanks for the help

Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One nice method uses updatable CTEs:

```
with todelete as (
      select uiap.*,
             row_number() over (partition by TransactionID order by id) as seqnum
     from UserInAppPurchase uiap
    )
delete todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

You can, of course, use other methods that are more compatible with other databases, such as:

```
delete uiap from UserInAppPurchase uiap
    where uiap.id > (select min(uiap2.id) from UserInAppPurchase uiap2 where uiap2.TransactionID = uiap.TransactionID);
```